# sharepoint 2013 on windows 10

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, windows

I know This is not related to development, please accept me this time. I'm looking to upgrade windows 8.1 to windows 10 .

Can I able to install SharePoint 2013 on windows 10?

I couldn't find any articles about SharePoint support on win 10.

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint is a server product, that needs to be installed on a Server edition of Windows (Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, etc.). There's technical methods to deploy it on a client OS, but this is for evaluation purposes only... and I definetely don't recommend it as it will have serious side-effects.

Comment: yes.. absolutely you are right @Evariste , Im asking for personal use , we can install Sharepoint on win 7/8 FYI see this link http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx

Comment: Windows 10, would be nice. Have you got it working?

Comment: only win server we can install, else require vm workstation or vm ware...

Answer (score 3):

You can create VMs on your Win 10 and on this VM-Hyper V - you can install Windows server 2012 and SQL server 2012 for installing SP 2013.

Blog by [Bill Baer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/10/10/setting-up-a-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-101.aspx) will make your life easy.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way to do it. Set up a VM running Server 2012 and install SharePoint onto it. Yes, I know it's going to be slow but slow beats never quite knowing if a bug is an issue with running it on 10 or an actual thing you have to quash.

Comment: It requires the same executables and services on Windows 10 and a server OS.  There is literally no difference between a SharePoint installation on Windows Server and Windows 10.  The difference is you can't, reliably anyways, run production systems client OS.  But those differences are outside of SharePoint and related to IIS and SQL Server and what they support.  But for development and evaluation purposes, installing on Windows 10 is fine.  I've done it multiple times successfully without issues.

Answer (score -2):

To Install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 10 look [here](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/33/Install-SharePoint-on-Windows-10)
http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/33/Install-SharePoint-on-Windows-10

Comment: Link only answers do not help much. Please brief description and explain.

Comment: The provided link is broken.